# i always get these type of errors when ever i try to install any thing

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string '/home/syss/Documents/frontend_schedbe/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/fesm2020/ngx-bootstrap-modal.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 14.0.6, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade your angular version. Check out the [link](https://update.angular.io/) it should be helpful for upgrading the version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As it is clear from your question that it is telling you to `upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular`.

Comment: i did but it keeps coming